# Trying to make match on a rule that uses "recursive" identifier in flex

Tags: c, flex-lexer

I have this line:

```
0, 6 -> W(1) L(#);
```

or

```
\# -> @shift_right R W(1) L
```

I have to parse this line with flex, and take every element from every part of the arrow and put it in a list. I know how to match simple things, but I don't know how to match multiple things with the same rule. I'm not allowed to increase the limit for rules. I have a hint: parse the pieces, pieces will then combine, and I can use states, but I don't know how to do that, and I can't find examples on the net. Can someone help me?

So, here an example:

{

a -> W(b) #invert_loop;

b -> W(a) #invert_loop;

-> L(#)

}

When this section begins I have to create a structure for each line, where I put what is on the left of -> in a vector, those are some parameters, and the right side in a list, where each term is kinda another structure. For what is on the right side I wrote rules:

writex W([a-zA-Z0-9.#]) for W(anything).

So I need to parse these lines, so I can put the parameters and the structures int the big structure. Something like this(for the first line):

new bigStruc with param = a and list of struct = W(anything), #invert(it is a notation for a reference to another structure)

So what I need is to know how to parse these line so that I can create and create and fill these bigStruct, also using to rules for simple structure(i have all I need for these structures, but I don't how to parse so that I can use these methods).

Sorry for my English and I hope this time I was more clear on what I want.

Last-minute editing: I have matched the whole line with a rule, and then work on it with strtok. There is a way to use previous rules to see what type of structure i have to create? I mean not to stay and put a lots of if, but to use writex W([a-zA-Z0-9.#]) to know that i have to create that kind of structure?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note that the accepted way of saying 'Thanks' on these sites is to up-vote helpful answers to your questions (and good answers and good questions provided by other people), and to 'Accept' one of the answers to your questions as the most helpful. (Until you have a little more reputation, you can't do all that much up-voting, but you can accept answers to your questions, and doing so will boost your reputation too, slightly.) Please see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and especially [How do I ask questions here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Comment: Why do you need to process the whole list in Flex?  Grammars are good for handling lists; scanners are not.  If you do need to do it in Flex, then what are the tokenization rules?  'Words separated by blanks'?  Or is `@shift_right` two tokens and `W(1)` 4 tokens?

Comment: How are you defining elements? Spaces, punctuation, special chars? Lists are not a native c data structure, so are you using a library, or are you putting items into an array? Do you want the actual token in the list, or something that represents it?

Comment: I have to use flex.This grammar ignore whitespaces. The left part of -> are some conditions; if parsing a string, if we are on one of those symbols to do the right part of ->. So what i want is: if a condition is fulfilled, i have to do some action; for those action i have defined some rules in case that they are simple, without any other things around him. So if in my string i want to parse i have 6, in a list i must put(i am not interested on putting on list, but a way of parsing to say W(x) {put_list(funct)}) an "object" that writes 1. There could be numbers, letters or other symbols.

Comment: The conditions are separated by commas and the actions by spaces. They have ; at the end if there are more of these structures and the last one doesn't have anything at the end {
  0 -> W(1) L(#);
  1 -> W(0) #addone_loop;
  # -> @shift_right R W(1) L
 } Braces are used to know when these kind of structures begin and end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, lets see how this snippet works for you:

```
// these are exclusive rules, so they do not overlap, for inclusive rules, use %s
%x dataStructure
%x addRules
%%
<dataStructure>-> { BEGIN addRules; }
\{                { BEGIN dataStructure; }
<addRules>;       { BEGIN dataStructure; }
<dataStructure>\} { BEGIN INITIAL; }

<dataStructure>[^,]+ { ECHO; } //this will output each comma separated token
<dataStructure>. { } //ignore anything else
<dataStructure>\n { } //ignore anything else
<addRules>[^ ]+ { ECHO; } //this will output each space separated rule
<addRules>. { } //ignore anything else
<addRules>\n { } //ignore anything else
%%
```

I'm not entirely sure what it it you want. Edit your original post to include the contents of your comments, with examples, and please structure your English better. If you can't explain what you want without contradicting yourself, I can't help you.